# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] is empty if link is being opened in a new Tab?

Tags: php

Not sure if this has been asked before but I couldn't find anything useful about it.

I'm using PHP 5.7. I want to capture the user's HTTP_REFERER on my own web pages. However, it looks like if I'm using a `target="_blank"` when making links, I'm unable to capture the user's HTTP REFERER on the next page.

On the other hand, it looks like that if I'm right clicking on the link (or CTRL + click), then I can capture it.

What's the difference? Is this the usual and expected behavior?

Comment: You can't rely 100% on the referrer, both because it might not be set - but it can also be spoofed, like anything clientside

Comment: @Qirel Yeah agreed. How's it possible then to know from which page my users are coming from? Is there any method that people are using for this? I want to see from which page the user was coming from and display different content based on that.

Comment: The referer should be purely informational, e.g. for traffic analysis. Since you cannot depend on it at all, you shouldn't be using it for anything important.

Comment: If they come from your website, you can use a session variable you set each time they load a page. It's not fool-proof either though.

Comment: @Qirel Yeah thought about that also, the issue is though that I'm using 2 different domain names on the same server.